# Increment value in accordance to the number of corresponding keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hashmap

I have a hash-map, where I'm trying to increment the value in accordance to the number of times a key is pushed into the array.

For Example, lets say the following is my hash-map

```
{
c => 0,
def => 0
}
```

The next time when I'm trying to push c into the hash-map, the output should be

```
{
c => 1,
def => 0
}
```

Comment: push to a hash map? please add an example how to do.

Comment: by pushing c into the object,  i assume you are trying to assign a new value to c ?

Comment: and what you tried is...?

Comment: You could use a sorted linked list and a hashtable to look up a certain node by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you described in your question you first need to check if the property 'c' exists in the object you can do that like this:

```
var myObj = {c: 0, function: null}
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty('c')){
  // the property exists
  myObj['c'] = myObj['c'] + 1;
} else {
 myObj['c'] = 0;
}
```

this is hardcoded example I will show you how to do that with a function:

```
var myObj = {c: 0, function: null};

function insert(obj, myProp){
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(myProp)){
 // the property exists
 obj[myProp] = obj[myProp] + 1;
} else {
 obj[myProp] = 0;
}

insert(myObj, 'c');
```